# How can I prevent user from specifying a function template parameter, forcing it to be deduced?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a template function:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B>
A fancy_cast(B)
{
    return {};
}
```

The intended usage is something like `fancy_cast<int>(1.f)`.

But nothing stops the user from specifying the second template parameter manually: `fancy_cast<int, int>(1.f)`, which would cause problems.

How can I prevent `typename B` from being specified and force it to be deduced?

I've come up with this:

```cpp
// Using this wrapper prevents the code from being
// ill-formed NDR due to [temp.res]/8.3
template <auto V> inline constexpr auto constant_value = V;

template <
    typename A,
    typename ...Dummy,
    typename B,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<constant_value<sizeof...(Dummy)> == 0>
>
A fancy_cast(B)
{
    return {};
}
```

It appears to work, but it's *extremely* cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good-looking solution.

We can use a non-type parameter pack, of a type that the user can't construct.<sup>1</sup> E.g. a reference to a hidden class:

```cpp
namespace impl
{
    class require_deduction_helper
    {
      protected:
        constexpr require_deduction_helper() {}
    };
}

using require_deduction = impl::require_deduction_helper &;

template <typename A, require_deduction..., typename B>
A fancy_cast(B)
{
    return {};
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> We do have to leave a loophole for constructing a `deduction_barrier`, otherwise the code would be [ill-formed NDR](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.3). That's why the constructor is protected.

Comment: @M.Mac Do you mean for all possible `A` and `B`? I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: I don't think that you need `protected`, `require_deduction...` doesn't require to be empty (contrary to `enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == 0>`). It is not because you cannot construct some values that template is invalid. Similarly, `struct S{}; using member_ptr_t = void (S::*)();` is valid, even if `S` has no members.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm. As I read it, the clause says you have to be able to create a valid specialization with a non-empty pack, or it's ill-formed NDR. `member_ptr_t` can be initialized with `nullptr`, but if it couldn't then I'd say you couldn't make a parameter pack out of it.

Answer (score 4):

What about making `fancy_cast` a variable template?

```
template <typename A>
struct fancy_cast_t {
    template <typename B>
    A operator()(B x) const { return x; }
};

template <typename A>
constexpr fancy_cast_t<A> fancy_cast {};

fancy_cast<int>(1.5);  // works
fancy_cast<int, int>(1.5);  // doesn't work
fancy_cast<int>.operator()<int>(1.5);  // works, but no one would do this
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most efficient solution, but you can create a class that has a template parameter for the type to convert to, and then have a constructor template that takes any type.  Then if you add an `operator T` for the type you instantiate the class with you can have that return correct value.  That would look like

```
template<typename T>
struct fancy_cast
{
    T ret;
    template<typename U>
    fancy_cast(U u) : ret(u) {} // or whatever you want to do to convert U to T
    operator T() && { return std::move(ret); }
};

int main()
{
    double a = 0;
    int b = fancy_cast<int>(a);
}
```

This works because there is no way to specify the template parameter for the constructor since you can't actually call it.